# WPF Toggle button code behind not in keeping with mvvm design

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application that contains a datagrid. In the datagrid some of the rowheaders contain a toggle button (this is based on a property of of the underlying object that is bound to the datagrid).

Currently when a user clicks a toggle button it will display or collapse the row details. This all works fine. However the issue is for the toggle button to display and collapse the row details I have some code behind which is not in keeping with the mvvm design I am trying to implement.

I have tried to convert this code into xaml without any success, I'm not sure its even possible? How do I keep my MVVM desing in tack?

In my application I have some buttons (seperate to the datagrid) which I have exposed using the ICommand interface is it possible to do something similar with the two methods below? Have been trying to find a solution since yesterday but getting no where!

C# Code

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to achieve would require changing the header template of the datagrid and simply binding some part of it to your object.  In any case, could you post some code?

Comment: Hi Doc, for some reason it won't let me post any code, rather fustrating! Trying to edit my question but will not let me add any code at the moment, its strange. Please bear with me.

Comment: your toggle button is pure UI, so that's nothing to do with MVVM (not in ViewModel !). You can do it in code behind, or in xaml, as you want.

Comment: It is not a sin to use code behind, relax. Xaruth is right.

Comment: @mHelpMe If you'd like, just post the code (even if it doesn't show up) and I will format it for you